# pandas custom file format parsing

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, io

I have data in the following format:

`1_engineer_grade1 |Boolean IsMale IsNorthAmerican IsFromUSA |Name blah
2_lawyer_grade7 |Boolean IsFemale IsAlive |Children 2`

I need to convert this into a dataframe with the following columns:

```
id job      grade Bool.IsMale Bool.IsFemale Bool.IsAlive Bool.IsNorthAmerican Bool.IsFromUSA Name Children
1  engineer 1     True        False         False        True                 True           blah NaN
2  lawyer   7     False       True          True         True                 False          NaN  2
```

I could preprocess this data in python and then call `pd.DataFrame` on this, but I was wondering if there was a *better* way of doing this?

**UPDATE:** I ended up doing the following: If there are obvious optimizations, please let me know

```
with open(vwfile, encoding='latin-1') as f:
    data = []
    for line in f:
        line = [x.strip() for x in line.strip().split('|')]
        # line == [
        #    "1_engineer_grade1",
        #    "|Boolean IsMale IsNorthAmerican IsFromUSA",
        #    "|Name blah"
        # ]
        ident, job, grade = line[0].split("_")
        features = line[1:]
        bools = {
            "IsMale": False,
            "IsFemale": False,
            "IsNorthAmerican": False,
            "IsFromUSA": False,
            "IsAlive": False,
        }
        others = {}
        for category in features:
            if category.startswith("Bools "):
                for feature in category.split(' ')[1:]:
                    bools[feature] = True
            else:
                feature = category.split(" ")
                # feature == ["Name", "blah"]
                others[feature[0]] = feature[1]
        featuredict = {
            'ident': ident,
            'job': job,
            'grade': grade,
        }            
        featuredict.update(bools)
        featuredict.update(others)
        data.append(featuredict)
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

**UPDATE-2** A million line file took about 55 seconds to process this.

Comment: Yeah, you definitely need to preprocess this yourself, there really isn't a simple way to do it. Please show your efforts.

Comment: i would try to read data in pyhton, parse with regex and do some post processing. You could make regex groups of the several options and then make your dataframe from the match groups.